# Redirect requests (htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?site\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif)$ gif.php [L]
```

As i know, its redirecting ALL requests to *.gif files. How i must to edit this rule to redirect requests only /uploads/ folder?

Sorry for my English (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect requests to GIF files inside the /uploads/ path, you'll do:

```
RewiteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?site\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/uploads/.*\.gif$ gif.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?site\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule uploads/.*\.gif$ gif.php [L]
```

Now it redirects only request made to a gif file inside `uploads` folder.

Be careful, it's redirecting everything to a `gif.php` inside your document root. The `uploads` folder will not be part of the new request.